# Is it Possible to Reflect the XAML Markup for VS2012?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, decompiling

I have been looking at some components Microsoft use for VS2012, attempting to learn and use there approaches to extensible component design. Despite being able to decompile the C#, I cannot seem to find any way of looking at the XAML mark-up, is this possible?

Note. I have attempted using Snoop but this does not seem to be able to provide the relevant XAML.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Reflector has a BAML to XAML plug in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a commercial [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) with BAML Viewer to convert BAML resource of assembly to XAML.

Also you could use a free [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) decompiler. Since 1.1  version it has a feature to view BAML resources without any additional plug-ins.

At last you could use a open source [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) decompiler to solve the same problem.